# Orthogonal complement of continuous functions on $(0,1)$ where $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

> What is the orthogonal complement of $Y = \{ f \in C(0,1):f(1/2) = 0 \}$?

> What about $X = \{1, x\}$ in $C[0,1]$

The dot product is naturally $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx$.

I had no idea how to tackle this question from my exam. Judging by the points possible it wasn't that hard.

I felt like the $X^{{\perp}}$ would be $Span(\{0, x^2, x^3, \dots \})$ but wasn't able to prove it rigourously.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you thinking that $X^\perp$ is not a vector space?

Comment: Oh, it is a vector space, so I need to add ${0}$ to the set.

Comment: Do you believe that $\{0,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$ is a vector space?

Comment: No. But a linear combination of it would be a vector space, ...right?

Comment: The span of any subset of a vector space is a vector space. On the other hand, do you believe that $\left\langle1,x^k\right\rangle=0$ for each $k\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$?

Comment: Duh. I do not. So my idea was entirely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$ because $Y$ is dense. Given any continuous function $f$ let $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for $|x-\frac 1 2| >\frac 1 n$, $f_n(\frac  1 2)=0$ and let $f_n$ be linear in $[\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 n, \frac  1 2]$ and $[\frac 1 2, \frac 1 n+ \frac  1 2]$. Then $f_n \in Y$ and $f_n \to f$ in the norm induced by the inner product.